# C# What is mistyped override ToString() even doing?

Tags: c#, tostring

In C#, the compiler allows and builds :

```
public string Override() {  return Name + " : " + StartTime; }
```

in a object that has a Name string property and StartTime datetime property.
Here is what someone on my team should have coded:

```
public override string ToString() { return Name + " : " + StartTime;  }
```

What is the original code even doing?

Comment: That is just a method named `Override`. Nothing special about it

Answer (score 3):

The first code example creates a new method called `Override()` which returns those properties. The keyword `override` is case sensitive, so the method `Override()` is perfectly fine.